# objectFilter doesn't seem to be working

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

When I tried to pull all the invoice items with the below objectFilter, it didn't return the expected item count. I was expecting around 10 items but it returned 400 records. As per the invoice the count should be round 10. Could you please help me on this?

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/12600077/getObject?objectFilter={"items":{"hostName":{"operation":"1212test11"},"domainName":{"operation":"gravitant.com"}}}&objectMask=mask[id,items[id,description,hostName,domainName]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep that kind of situations is very common using object filters this is because not all properties can be filters, in some cases there is a workaround in other nope.

For your case I found this workaournd:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Billing_Invoice/12600077/getItems?objectFilter={"items":{"hostName":{"operation":"1212test11"}},"domainName":{"operation":"gravitant.com"}}&objectMask=mask[id,description,hostName,domainName]
```

You need to use the method getItems which already return all the items and with that method you can apply the filter

Regards